# Need to Create a page to display all the account records existing the instance.

Tags: custom-button, account, visualforce, record

Need to Create a page to display all the account records existing the instance. It should display 20 records in one page and should have NEXT & PREVIOUS button to navigate to other records.

**but  it should not fetch more than 20 records in single query.**

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is the create a Visualforce page the calls the controller to fetch the record using JavaScript Remoting. There is also a somewhat new OFFSET keyword which makes pagination a breeze.

Comment: Seems like the right architecture, a code sample would make this a great answer.

Comment: I'm sitting on the runway on my phone so rather difficult at the moment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was actually trying to write something for a coding example, but came across this answer that @sfdcfox came up with.  It's actually a really cool trick to use, and I'm actually going to play around with it, as it seems like a pretty simple and elegant way to workaround the limit of 2000 rows for using OFFSET in SOQL.

Looks like exactly what would help for your scenario.  I would check this out.

[How can I use 'query more' using javascript remoting?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/how-can-i-use-query-more-using-javascript-remoting)

Answer (score 1):

For up to 10k records, you can use the StandardSetController:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!first}" value="First"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!previous}" value="Previous"/>
                {!pagenumber}
                <apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="Next"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!last}" value="Last"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="account">
                <apex:column value="{!account.name}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If you add a custom controller or extension, you can assign any query up to 10,000 rows for automatic pagination. Take a look at the StandardSetController documentation for further examples.